# Can not deduce reboot reason

Tags: crash, reboot

My server (runs on UBuntu 16.04) and suddenly yesterday (03.04) at 22:28 it went down (reboot), there is an insane long log about it, but I can not deduce what exactly went wrong, can gurus of Ubuntu please point me in the right direction or tell me reason for my debacle.

Here is full logs file https://codeshare.io/5eXnAl

Comment: Bad news. Sorry ... `/dev/sda` drive might be failing. Check `SMART` info

Comment: well, at first look it doesn't look like its hard drive's problem, though I started long smart selftest to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, those logs do not say why it went down.  It actually stopped at 22:26 and probably hung for a bit.  Booted back up at 22:28.  You might be able to see maybe closer to the time it rebooted by running `last -x`.  In my experience, unless this is actual server hardware, it is very hard to find out why it crashed, etc.  Server hardware sometimes you can run `ipmitool sel elist` and might be able to see bad hardware causing issues.

Comment: @Terrance got this from last -x https://codeshare.io/2jwXAD
Though I couldn't run ipmitool sel elist ( how exactly this command goes? )

Comment: The `ipmitool` command is used for actual server hardware that has a BMC/LOM on it.  I saw in your logs that OpenIPMI was starting, so it had me question it, but if the command doesn't work for you chances are it is not server hardware.  Honestly, I would look into bad hardware like running RAM tests and things like that on your system.  Also, if it doesn't reboot again, it might have just been an anomaly.

Comment: Since nothing useful was logged, some kind of hardware fault is a definite possibility: Power hiccup, overheat, etc.

Comment: @Terrance well the only server hardware is xeon w3530 cpu, I guess. Well I hope there won't be more reboots, but will keep an eye on it.

BTW Offtopic question, can I ask things about nginx+ubuntu on this website?

Comment: I have seen questions here about nginx https://askubuntu.com/search?q=nginx but I know nothing about nginx.  So, feel free to ask about it.

Comment: @Terrance thank you, this will help a lot.